# make barplot of groups with error bars

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to make a barplot of the columns V2 and length. I would also plot the standard deviation from the number in `length` for each group.

```
> head(Length_filter3)
             V1    V2                                           V3 length
1 URS00000081EA snRNA               AAACTCGACTGCATAATTTGTGGTAGTGGG     30
2 URS00000081EA snRNA              AAACTCGACTGCATAATTTGTGGTAGTGGGG     31
3 URS00000081EA snRNA          AAACTCGACTGCATAATTTGTGGTAGTGGGGGACT     35
4 URS0000008112A tRNA          AAACTCGACTGCATAATTTGTGGTAGTGGGGGACTG     36
5 URS000000812A  tRNA  AAATGTGGGAAACTCGACTGCATAATTTGTGGTAGTGGGGGACT     44
6 URS0000008121EA tRNA                 AACTCGACTGCATAATTTGTGGTAGTGGG     29


ggplot(Length_filter3, aes(V2,length)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

Comment: `length` is a single number for each bar. Single numbers don't have standard deviations. Please clarify.

Comment: @user2300940 It would be polite if you acknowledged answers that work for you, to the many questions you've been asking.  *What should I do when someone answers my question?*   http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that you are looking to create some sort of summary statistic, such as average, rather than trying to plot the total length of all of the RNA types (for which there would be no error bar to speak of).

If it has to be a bar plot, you will likely need to calculate the values yourself. Here, I am manually calculating the ranges I want from the `iris` data (using `dplyr`):

```
summarizedData <-
  iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarise(
    mean = mean(Petal.Length)
    , sd = sd(Petal.Length)
    , low = mean + sd/(sqrt(n())) * qt(0.025, n()-1 )
    , high = mean + sd/(sqrt(n())) * qt(0.975, n()-1 )
  )


ggplot(
  summarizedData
  , aes(x = Species
        , y = mean
        , ymax = high
        , ymin = low)
) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_linerange()
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can let `ggplot` do the work for you, particularly if you are willing to use points and error bars instead of a bar plot (I tend to prefer it this way)

```
ggplot(
  iris
  , aes(x = Species
        , y = Petal.Length)
) +
  stat_summary(fun.data = mean_cl_normal)
```

[image]

You can combine these approaches if you like as well.

Answer (score 0):

try `FUN` function in `ggplot` choosing stdev.

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, a good answer also demonstrates the solution.  Please [edit] to provide example code to show what you mean. Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead.